# Vue js on click get html5 attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am doing a project using vuejs latest version. In this project I want to get html5 attribute associating vue on click event.

my button code is

```
<a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" @click="editModal" data_id="{{$staff->id}}">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</a>
```

and my js is

```
var staffModal = new Vue({
el: '#app',
methods: {
    editModal: function(){
        console.log(this.data_id);
    }
}});
```

In my `console` I get `undefined`. How to get right value.

Answer (score 29):

[MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) instance is passed as 1st parameter to click event handler. Use `getAttribute` function to access attribute. `MouseEvent.target` will point to `<i>` and `MouseEvent.currentTarget` to `<a>` (element that the event listener is attached to).
Change your editModal method to:

```
editModal: function(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data_id'));
}
```

BTW: use - (dash) not _ (underscore) to create data attributes: correct is `data-id` not `data_id`

Comment: Problem solved. It will be `currentTarget` not `target`. Reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/39357594/4555551

Comment: @IftakharulAlam thx, updated answer, didnt notice nested <i> in your question

Comment: Try using `data-` instead of `data_` and you will be able to use `e.target.dataset`

Answer (score 17):

You have some things wrong in your code.
Let's start with HTML code.

When you need to interpolate an attribute, you must use v-bind. So you have two ways to do that. Using `v-bind:attribute="expression"` or the shorthand `:attribute="expression"`. Using `attribute="{{ expression }}"` will definitely not work.

Another important thing, to use a custom attribute name, you should use `data-custom-attribute-name` instead of `data_custom-attribute-name`.

```
<div id="app">
  <a
    href="javascript:"
    class="btn btn-info btn-xs"
    @click="editModal"
    :data-id="staff.id"
    :data-my-amazing-custom-attribute="staff.name">
    Click me!
  </a>
</div>
```

Now, let's go to JS. From your question I couldn't know where the $staff variable comes from, so I made an adaptation to demonstrate.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    editModal: function(event){
      // Here you will be able to see all the
      // custom attributes in camelCase
      console.log(event.target.dataset);
      console.log('ID:', event.target.dataset.id);
      console.log('Name:', event.target.dataset.myAmazingCustomAttribute);
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      staff: {
        id: 'some id',
        name: 'Name of my amazing custom attribute'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You can check a working version here: https://jsfiddle.net/6v3wyoh6/

Hope it helps!

Comment: somethimes it will return currect value and sometimes `undefined`

Comment: @IftakharulAlam, in the example I've provided?

Comment: for me, `this.$el.dataset.myAmazingCustomAttribute`  worked

Answer (score 7):

Getting the `id` from a data attribute is fine, and will work, but my question would be, why? You're using Vue, so *use Vue*. You can pass the `id` *directly*.

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" @click="editModal({{$staff->id}})">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</a>
```

And your Vue code becomes

```
methods: {
    editModal: function(id){
        console.log(id);
    }
}
```

Now you don't need to worry about figuring out what the data attribute is. That's DOM manipulation that you should generally *avoid* when using Vue because it is unnecessary.

Note: I'm assuming here you are using laravel or something similar such that when `{{$staff->id}}` is rendered it is rendered as your `id`.

Comment: The only solution on this thread that worked. 10 pts for Griffyndor

Answer (score 0):

here the link to [vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event). Exactly the right way to emit a value to an eventhandler.

```
    <button v-on:click="$emit('enlarge-text', 0.1)">
       Enlarge text
    </button>
```