# Is it better to pass in $event vs implying?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is it better practice to pass in the event when using it in a method or to just have it implied:

option1:

```
<input @keyup.enter="chooseMe($event)"/>
```

option2:

```
<input @keyup.enter="chooseMe"/>
```

---

```
chooseMe(evt) {
    console.log(evt)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you are asking about performance rather than developer opinion.  (For example, it could be argued that explicitly passing the `$event` argument makes the component's intention clearer, but that's an opinion.  It's also more verbose.)

The compiler generates a wrapper function around any handler that uses a function invocation (i.e. `()` in the attribute value), to allow for passing `$event` as an argument.  When using modifiers like `.enter` in your example, it does this even if there is no invocation.

To test any performance impact, you can use a test suite like [JSBench.me](https://jsbench.me/).  Here are the results of such a [test](https://jsbench.me/zwklp8zx67) running on Windows/Chrome.

1. **Implicit**

```
<div @click="test"></div>
```

**Result:**: ~*502,653* operations per second.

2. **Explicit**

```
<div @click="test($event)"></div>
```

**Result:**: ~*536,685* operations per second.

It's faster (by an imperceptible margin) to include the `$event` in this case.  But the difference is insignificant enough to be irrelevant.  If you had to compile 500,000 event handlers, the act of compilation for both syntaxes would take around 1 second.

Comment: Don't feel bad that the question got closed, it's a good question.  They misunderstood that you weren't asking about stylistic opinion, but performance and/or factual differences.

Answer (score 0):

In Option1 you create an expression each time the component gets rendered. But, in Option2 in each cycle, just one method is addressed. So, it's better to define methods and address them in the template.

Consider this sample:

```
<list>
  <li
      v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"
      @click="theClickHandler(item)"
  ></li>
</list>
```

There are a `theClickHandler` method and `item.length` different expressions in each render (at most)!!

To handle this situation you can use [HTML data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44324869/vue-js-on-click-get-html5-attribute):

```
<list>
  <li
      v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"
      :data-id="item.id"
      @click="theClickHandler"
  ></li>
</list>
```

and get the clicked item in hanlder method:

```
theClickHandler(e) {
  const id = e.target.dataset.id
  const [item] = this.items.filter(x => x.id === id)
  console.log('clicked item:', item)
},
```